# jquery hotkeys for spacebar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to use [jquery hotkeys](https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys) to capture keypress events. I am unable to capture spacebar press. Does anyone know a place where all the keypress codes for hotkeys is listed?

My code:

```
$(document).bind('keypress', 'spacebar', function(){
    alert('spacebar pressed');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you can refer key codes [here](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes),

```
$(document).bind('keypress', function(e){
    var key = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.charCode; //get the key code
    if (key == 32 && e.ctrlKey){//key code of space bar
        alert('spacebar pressed with ctrl key..');
     }
});
```

Comment: These are the key codes for regular js. I am checking for jquery hotkeys - for eg. "ctrl+a" is control key and A key pressed together...

Answer (score 0):

Lines 26 - 113 of [jquery.hotkeys.js](https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys/blob/master/jquery.hotkeys.js) have a number of keys which are readable.

`32: "space"`

You want to use "space" instead of "spacebar".

The plugin uses `String.fromCharCode(event.which)` for 'normal' keys.

```
specialKeys: {
  8: "backspace",
  9: "tab",
  10: "return",
  13: "return",
  16: "shift",
  17: "ctrl",
  18: "alt",
  19: "pause",
  20: "capslock",
  27: "esc",
  32: "space",
  33: "pageup",
  34: "pagedown",
  35: "end",
  36: "home",
  37: "left",
  38: "up",
  39: "right",
  40: "down",
  45: "insert",
  46: "del",
  59: ";",
  61: "=",
  96: "0",
  97: "1",
  98: "2",
  99: "3",
  100: "4",
  101: "5",
  102: "6",
  103: "7",
  104: "8",
  105: "9",
  106: "*",
  107: "+",
  109: "-",
  110: ".",
  111: "/",
  112: "f1",
  113: "f2",
  114: "f3",
  115: "f4",
  116: "f5",
  117: "f6",
  118: "f7",
  119: "f8",
  120: "f9",
  121: "f10",
  122: "f11",
  123: "f12",
  144: "numlock",
  145: "scroll",
  173: "-",
  186: ";",
  187: "=",
  188: ",",
  189: "-",
  190: ".",
  191: "/",
  192: "`",
  219: "[",
  220: "\\",
  221: "]",
  222: "'"
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that link.Yes it looks like its space by reading that, however it does not work for me when I type "space"...if I give "A" or some other letter, then it traps that keypress correctly...this is very frustrating :(

Answer (score 0):

you can use this jquery plugin https://gist.github.com/d194103a0c9b11248a32.git

example

```
$('div').hotkey('space bar', function() {
  alert("Spacebar pressed....");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For me also "space" doesn't work. I used the code instead:

```
$('div').hotkey(32, function() {
  alert("Spacebar pressed....");
});
```